# How to specify .deb package is platform-specific but for any platform?

Tags: debian, dpkg, deb

I am building a custom package for Debian which I then intend to deploy to other machines.  To keep things simple, I'm just installing the `.deb` file directly with `dpkg -i`.

According to the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Architecture) you can use the special words `all` for an architecture-independent package, and `any` for an architecture-dependent package that can be built for any number of different architectures.

So I have gone ahead and written `Architecture: any` in my control file, however when I go to install the package, I get this error:

```
 package architecture (any) does not match system (amd64)
```

Why is the package being created for the `any` architecture?  This is not an architecture-independent package (which is why I didn't write `all`), so it looks like `dpkg` is not replacing `any` with the architecture the package was compiled for.

What is the correct way to specify that a package is platform-specific but it can be built for all available platforms?  I don't want to have to list all of them, there are hundreds!

**UPDATE:** The build process is a simple `configure && make && make install PREFIX=/xyz` and then I'm making the package with `fakeroot dpkg -b /xyz /output`

Is there a standard way to replace 'any' with the current architecture automatically, or should I e.g. be using `sed` to modify the control file?

Comment: It's not `dpkg` that has to replace `any` with the name of the actual architecture, but the build process. Please show us (editi it in to the question), the actual commands you use, and preferably their output (there can be a lot of output from building, so please filter it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've updated the question.  `dpkg` produces little output (just the name of the `.deb` file with the architecture as `any`) and the `configure` process is much the same as any other.

Comment: That is not a good way of building debian packages. As far as I could gather from a quick look at the manpage for `dpkg-deb` (the man page for `dpkg` refers to that for the `-b` option) all it does is wrap things up in a `.deb` file. Please read (http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)[Debian New Maintainers' Guide].

Comment: Yes this isn't a good way of building Debian packages, but I suppose that's not really what I'm doing.  I'm using `dpkg` as a convenient way to deploy custom software to a Debian machine, with `dpkg` taking care of removing old files after an upgrade and installing dependencies.  I guess the answer in this case is to use `sed` then?

Comment: If you want to use `dpkg` you have to build debian packages! Trying to use it for anything else is a way of f*cking your system.

Comment: How so?  `dpkg` is pretty robust and won't let you do anything silly like overwrite files in use by other packages.  The alternative - `make install` has no such protection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating raw packages without any of the tooling to build them, contained in the `dpkg-dev` package. The usual way to generate binary packages is with a source package, which would contain the master control file where `any` is a valid architecture, that then gets transformed into the correct one by `dpkg-gencontrol` which gets called from `debian/rules`.

In any case I'd either recommend reading about packaging in the developers-reference or similar documents, both in case you decide to do standard packaging or if you decide to reimplement it from scratch.